# Loading a UIView with a UITableView from another NIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I have a NIB that contains a UIView.

I have another NIB that contains a UITableView.

How can I load the UITableView NIB inside of the UIView in my other NIB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is called a detached nib file in the Apple documentation.

I would read over [Storing the View in a Detached Nib File](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW33) in the View Programming Guide. It has all the info you need to do this.

Comment: Very helpful! When I add a UIViewController it seems to occupy the entire screen. I have to add my UIView as part of the UIViewController. I have some UILabels on my UIView. I want the UIViewController that loads my UITableView to appear below the UILabels on my UIView. Is that possible?